# ListBox Numbers, getting the average of the numbers

Tags: c#, listbox, streamreader

Here is the question to my problem:

"Use notepad to place the following values in a text file: 86, 97, 144, 26. To simplify the problem, the values can each be placed on separate lines.  Write a C# program to retrieve the values from the text file and print the average of the values, formatted with two decimal places.

I already have the text file show the list of the FOUR numbers in a list box titled... "lstBoxNumbers"

I am assuming the simply way is to take the numbers that it filtered into the listbox and use a foreach loop to calculate the average. I have decided to go the way of using a button click, to display the average in a text box. This is what i have so far.

```
private void btnAverage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Shows Average Of Numbers From Text File

    decimal average;

    txtAverage.Text = Convert.ToString(0);

    foreach (string itemInList in lstBoxNumbers.Items)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 2):

Try this: (You will have to cast the type to a double yourself since this is homework)

```
List<double> newNumberList = new List<double>(); // create a new list 

foreach (string itemInList in lstBoxNumbers.Items) // loop round all of your items
{
   newNumberList.Add(itemInList);  // You will have to convert this to a double, since this is homework you can research on how to convert types (Casting)
}   

 double avg = newNumberList.Average(); // Will give you the average you are looking for
```

Note the sample provided uses LINQ.  I assume your homework will be marked on the algorithm used to calculate the averages.  To acomplish this without using LINQ, in your foreach loop you want to keep track of the running total, so for every item you add you should append this to that total and then divide by how many items are in the list.

For example, if you had the following items in your list:

- 10
- 20
- 300
- 400

You would want the average to be 182.5   (10 + 20 + 300 + 400) / 4 items in the list

Answer (score 2):

Easy, but I kind of feel bad for answering your homework for you.  Turn the numbers into an Array or List then utilize Linq's Average method:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.average.aspx